# Is there any way to hide the collection view cell at particular index and to merge the two cells at particular index?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Is there any way to hide the collection view cell at particular index and to merge the two cells at particular index?I tried with hiding the cells but after scrolling i found that some of the remaining cells are also hiding due to reusability any suggestions regarding this issue